# Is there any calibration tool between two languages performance?

Tags: performance, programming-languages, evaluation

I'm measuring the performance of A and B programs. A is written in Golang, B is written in Python. The important point here is that I'm interested in how the performance value increases, not the absolute performance value of the two programs over time.
For example,

```
+------+-----+-----+
| time |  A  |  B  |
+------+-----+-----+
|  1   |  3  | 500 |
+------+-----+-----+
|  2   |  5  | 800 |
+------+-----+-----+
|  3   |  9  | 1300|
+------+-----+-----+
|  4   |  13 | 1800|
+------+-----+-----+
```

Where the values in columns A and B(A: 3, 5, 9, 13 / B: 500, 800, 1300, 1800) are the execution times of the program. This execution time can be seen as performance, and the difference between the absolute performance values of A and B is very large. Therefore, the slope comparison of the performance graphs of the two programs would be meaningless.(Python is very slow compared to Golang.)

I want to compare the performance of Program A written in Golang with Program B written in Python, and I'm looking for a calibration tool or formula based on benchmarks that calculates the execution time when Program A is written in Python.

Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the relative change, you should normalize the data for each programming language. In other words, divide the values for golang with 3 and for python, divide with value 500.

```
+------+-----+-----+
| time |  A  |  B  |
+------+-----+-----+
|  1   |  1  | 1   |
+------+-----+-----+
|  2   | 1.66| 1.6 |
+------+-----+-----+
|  3   |  3  | 2.6 |
+------+-----+-----+
|  4   |4.33 | 3.6 |
+------+-----+-----+
```